# Is there any documentation or tutorial on how to replicate the Blenrig 5 spine? or Rig an Armature controlled by its hips?

Tags: rigging

I would like to create a rig that is mainly controlled with the pelvis like Blenrig.

I've tried to reverse engineer a portion of the spine, so I have an understanding of how it works.
However I can't pull it off correctly.

Does anyone know whether there is a course, documents or tutorial on rigging a spine like such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed the spine.

I basically ripped the blenrig bare started with 1 set of bone groups and tried to link which bones were used and which weren't.

I now have a working spine controlled with the hips. image of it below.

Where i was going wrong was that the bones weren't parented to the correct bone and the torso master needs to be connected to another bone or you'll get the constraint glitch thing.

[image: relation lines and spine]